# Split corresponding column values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

Below table would be the input dataframe

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12;34;56 | Aus;SL;NZ |
| 2 | 31;54;81 | Ind;US;UK |
| 3 | null | Ban |
| 4 | Ned | null |

Expected output dataframe [values of col2 and col3 should be split by ; correspondingly]

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | Aus |
| 1 | 34 | SL |
| 1 | 56 | NZ |
| 2 | 31 | Ind |
| 2 | 54 | US |
| 2 | 81 | UK |
| 3 | null | Ban |
| 4 | Ned | null |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code works perfectly fine

```
data = [(1,'12;34;56', 'Aus;SL;NZ'),
        (2,'31;54;81', 'Ind;US;UK'),
        (3,None, 'Ban'),
        (4,'Ned', None) ]
  
columns = ['Id', 'Score','Countries']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns) 
#df.show()

df2=df.select("*",posexplode_outer(split("Countries",";")).alias("pos1","value1"))
#df2.show()

df3=df2.select("*",posexplode_outer(split("Score",";")).alias("pos2","value2"))
#df3.show()

df4=df3.filter((df3.pos1==df3.pos2) | (df3.pos1.isNull() | df3.pos2.isNull()))
df4=df4.select("Id","value2","value1")
df4.show()  #Final Output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pyspark function `split()` to convert the column with multiple values into an array and then the function `explode()` to make multiple rows out of the different values.

It may look like this:

```
df = df.withColumn("<columnName>", explode(split(df.<columnName>, ";")))
```

If you want to keep NULL values you can use `explode_outer()`.

If you want the values of multiple exploded arrays to match in the rows, you could work with `posexplode()` and then `filter()` to the rows where the positions are corresponding.

Comment: @restlessmodern
I need the values of those two columns to split corresponding to each other.
1st value of col2 should be mapped to 1st value of col3; 
2nd value of col2 should be mapped to 2nd value of col3

Comment: @VineethReddy I updated my answer with a possible solution.